# factory_bot build_stubbed strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

The [factory_bot documentation for build strategies](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#build-strategies) says:

> factory_bot supports several different build strategies: build, create, attributes_for and build_stubbed

And continues with some examples of usage. However, it doesn't clearly state what the result of each one is. I've been using `create` and `build` for a while now. `attributes_for` seems straightforward from the description and I see some uses for it. However, what is `build_stubbed`? The description says

> Returns an object with all defined attributes stubbed out

What does "stubbed out" mean? How is this different from either `create` or `build`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's consider the difference on the example of these factories:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    user
    title { 'Post title' }
    body { 'Post body' } 
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { 'John' }
    last_name { 'Doe' }
  end
end
```

**build**

With `build` method everything is easy. It returns a `Post` instance that's not saved

```rb
# initialization
post = FactoryBot.build(:post)
```

```rb
# call

p post
p post.user
```

```rb
# output
#<Post:0x00007fd10f824168> {
   :id => nil,
   :user_id => nil,
   :title => "Post title",
   :body => "Post body",
   :created_at => nil,
   :updated_at => nil
}

#<User:0x00007f8792ed9290> {
  :id => nil,
  :first_name => "Post title",
  :last_name => "Post body",
  :created_at => nil,
  :updated_at => nil
}
```

```rb
Post.all # => []
User.all # => []
```

**create**

With `create` everything is also quite obvious. It saves and returns a `Post` instance. But it calls all validations and callbacks and also creates associated instance of `User`

```rb
# initialization
post = FactoryBot.create(:post)
```

```rb
# call

p post
p post.user
```

```rb
# output

#<Post:0x00007fd10f824168> {
   :id => 1,
   :user_id => 1,
   :title => "Post title",
   :body => "Post body",
   :created_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00,
   :updated_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00
}
#<User:0x00007f8792ed9290> {
  :id => 1,
  :first_name => "John",
  :last_name => "Joe",
  :created_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00,
  :updated_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00
}
```

Post record and associated user record were created in the database:

```rb
Post.all # => [<Post:0x00007fd10f824168> {...}]

# User also created in the database
User.all # => [<User:0x00007f91af405b30> {...}]
```

**build_stubbed**

`build_stubbed` imitates creating. It slubs `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` and `user_id` attributes. Also it skips all validations and callbacks.

Stubs means that `FactoryBot` just initialize object and assigns values to the `id` `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes so that it **just looks like created**. For `id` it assign integer number `1001` (1001 is just default number what FactoryBot uses to assign to id), for `created_at` and `updated_at` assigns current datetime. And for every other record created with `build_stubbed` is will increment number to be assigned to id by 1.
First `FactoryBot` initialize `user` record and assign `1001` to `id` attribute but not save it to the database than it initialize `post` record and assing `1002` to the `id` attribute and `1001` to `user_id` attribute to make association, but also doesn't save record to the database.
See example below.

```rb
#initialization
post = FactoryBot.build_stubbed(:post)
```

```rb
# call

p post
p post.user
```

```rb
# output
# It looks like persisted instance
#<Post:0x00007fd10f824168> {
   :id => 1002,
   :user_id => 1001,
   :title => "Post title",
   :body => "Post body",
   :created_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00,
   :updated_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00
}

#<User:0x00007f8792ed9290> {
  :id => 1001,
  :first_name => "John",
  :last_name => "Joe",
  :created_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00,
  :updated_at => Sat, 18 Jun 2022 05:32:17.122906000 UTC +00:00
}
```

**Post and user records were not created in the database!!!**

```rb
# it is not persisted in the database
Post.all # => []

# Association was also just stubbed(initialized) and there are no users in the database.
User.all # => []
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still confused what `it stubs `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`" and `user_id` means, though. How is the output you show for `build_stubbed` different than what you show for `create`? I see the `id` and `user_id` values are different, but why? Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: Also, will you show the calls that create each block of output?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope it is clearer now;)

Comment: Thanks for the added detail. I believe it clears up my question. I'll need to work with it directly a bit more to see.